# Get details of All Class A operations in GCP Cloud Storage to Understand Cost

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-data-transfer

I am running a large data transfer between buckets using data transfer service for cloud storage.

I want to find out exactly how many times I am invoking `ClassA` operations and `ClassB` operations to understand and analyse cost trends.

Would like to know if there is an easy way to achieve it programmatically or via console ?

Answer (score 1):

## Enable Audit Logs

Follow the link and Enable Audit Logging for buckets in your projects with

```
Admin Read
Data Read
Data Write
```

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console

## Cloud Logging

### Most Class A Operations

Use this regex in cloud logging logs explorer to find out all classA operations invoked and select time frame as well

```
resource.type="gcs_bucket"
protoPayload.methodName=~"(storage.(buckets|objects|notifications|projects|.*AccessControls).(list|lockRetentionPolicy|compose|copy|rewrite|watchAll|delete|hmacKeys|insert|patch|update|setIamPolicy))"
```

### Most Class B Operations

Use this regex in cloud logging logs explorer to find out all classB operations invoked and select time frame as well

```
resource.type="gcs_bucket"
protoPayload.methodName=~"(storage.(.*).(get|getIamPolicy|testIamPermissions|AccessControls\.list|))"
```

To filter further your data, you can include principal

```
resource.type="gcs_bucket"
protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail=“test@test-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com "
```

#### *Note : It will increase the cost due to cloud logging.*